# want to make the revolution slider's height dynamic based on jQuery(window).height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

well am developing site called http://promomakerz.com/new i wanna change the revolution slider's height it depends on the

```
jQuery(window).height -jQuery('.navbar').height();
```

so i used made my jquery hacks to do so with this code

```
        jQuery(window).on('load resize',function(){
            var height_left = jQuery(window).height()-jQuery('.navbar').height();
            jQuery('#rev_Slider').css({height:height_left+'px'});
            jQuery('#rev_slider_1_1').css({height:height_left+'px'});
            jQuery('#rev_slider_1_1_wrapper').css({height:height_left+'px'});
            console.log("Slider Changed Successfully");
        });
```

and it did work but it reverse itself to the height written in the admin panel

guys am trying to fix this issue 2 days ago and its still on please help

Comment: I was looking at your site to try and help but couldn't think of a solution. But I wanted to let you know, your "to top" button goes behind your cards. Adding this in devTools fixed it, I recommend applying this or something similar to your CSS 

#topcontrol {
    z-index: 9999;
}

Comment: thanks alot i will do this am trying to figure out how can i controll the call back function to set the size as needed

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Sorry I couldn't figure out your original question.

Comment: its okay thank u anyway <3

Comment: u know how to trigger the done call back function of revolution slider ?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(. But while searching I think I found something that will have the answer. Check out this page, go to the very bottom, the section on the right "Actions, API and more", I think it will be there somewhere! 

https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/slider-revolution-jquery-5-x-documentation/

Comment: unfortunately no but am still looking for solution :( thanks for helping

Comment: oh my god !!!! 
thank god i've found the solution using the API 
its little bit tricky but it worked super fine <3 

solution :-

var api = revapi1; // the one refers to the slider id 
var height_left = jQuery(window).height()-jQuery('.navbar').height();
var sliderSettings = api.data('opt') || api[0].opt;
console.log(sliderSettings); // here u can see slider revapi1's settings
sliderSettings.height = height_left;
sliderSettings.conh = height_left;
sliderSettings.ulh = height_left;
sliderSettings.gridheight[0] = height_left;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh my god !!!! 
thank god i've found the solution using the API 
its little bit tricky but it worked super fine <3

solution :-

```
var api = revapi1; // the one refers to the slider id 
var height_left = jQuery(window).height()-jQuery('.navbar').height();
var sliderSettings = api.data('opt') || api[0].opt;
console.log(sliderSettings); // here u can see slider revapi1's settings
sliderSettings.height = height_left;
sliderSettings.conh = height_left;
sliderSettings.ulh = height_left;
sliderSettings.gridheight[0] = height_left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect thank you but I had to use a timeout for that it worked well

```
function resizeSlider() {
    var api = revapi1;
     var windowHeight = $(window).height();
     var height_left = windowHeight -  $('header.site-header').height() - $('#uid_581031dff187267690e9823b9a5b565a').height();  
     var sliderSettings = api.data('opt') || api[0].opt;
     //console.log(sliderSettings);
     setTimeout(function() {
        sliderSettings.height = height_left;
        sliderSettings.conh = height_left;
        sliderSettings.ulh = height_left;
        sliderSettings.gridheight[0] = height_left;
    },250);
}
$(window).resize(function(){
    resizeSlider();     
});
resizeSlider();
```

Answer (score 0):

The official offset-option could also work:

```
jQuery('#rev_slider_1').show().revolution({

    sliderLayout: 'auto',

    /* OFFSET SLIDER BY THE HEIGHT OF AN ELEMENT */
    fullScreenOffsetContainer: ".navbar",

    /* options continued .... */
```